# Tableview multiple sections button action for radio btn and checkbox in swift

Tags: swift, checkbox, radio-button, tableview, sections

In my application there are multiple sections namely checkbox and radio button.

In the tableview cell I created two UIButton, which changes depending on the response, if its checkbox or radio button.

here is my code.

```
var radioControllerChoice : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    var radioControllerDip : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    var radioControllerDrink : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    var radioControllerSides : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    var radioControllerOption : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return table_data.count
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:CustomiseTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Customise") as! CustomiseTableViewCell
        cell.name.text?=table_data[indexPath.section].menu_name[indexPath.row]
        print(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row])

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 2:
            radioControllerChoice.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
        case 3:
            radioControllerDip.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
        case 4:
            radioControllerDrink.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
        case 5:
            radioControllerSides.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
        case 6:
            radioControllerOption.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
        default:
            print("no case found")
        }

        switch Int(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row]) {
        case 1:
            cell.radioBtn.isHidden = true
            cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = false
            break
        case 2:
            cell.radioBtn.isHidden = false
            cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = true
            break
        default:
            print("Invalid choose")

        }
       cell.radioBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.didSelectButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.radioBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBoxBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkBoxBtnaction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }
```

table_data is the array, and I get the array values from web services using struct.

My problem is:

write the button action for radio button.

```
 func didSelectButton(selectedButton: UIButton?)
    {
        print("selectedButton",(selectedButton?.tag)!)
        let tagVal = (selectedButton?.tag)!
        print("tagVal",tagVal)

    }
```

In button click action choice is one separate sections in tableview show in image. **In that sections want to select and deselect the radio button. when select cheese it will selected, then I will select the triple layer cheese means, cheese automatically deselect. want to select only one item in that sections.**

**Each sections have a different item with radio button.

If selected one radio button it will select, after selected any other radio button means the pervious selected button want to deselect automatically. It should happen in each sections in tableview only for radio button.**

whatever the item selected want to store it in string.

The same button action need for check box with multiple selection.

```
func checkBoxBtnaction(sender:UIButton)
 {


 }
```

enter image description here

[image]

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController)  library for radio buttons and update your code with this and try

```
    var radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:CustomiseTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Customise") as! CustomiseTableViewCell
            cell.name.text?=table_data[indexPath.section].menu_name[indexPath.row]
            print(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row])

            radioButtonController.addButton(cell.radioBtn)

            switch Int(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row]) {
                case 1:
                    cell.radioBtn.isHidden = true
                    cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = false
                    break
                case 2:
                    cell.radioBtn.isHidden = false

                    cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = true
                    break
                default:
                    print("Invalid choose")

                }
                cell.radioBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.radioBtnaction), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.checkBoxBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkBoxBtnaction), for: .touchUpInside)

                return cell

            }
```

**EDIT:**

```
var radioControllerChoice : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
var radioControllerDip : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomiseTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Customise") as! CustomiseTableViewCell
    cell.name.text?=table_data[indexPath.section].menu_name[indexPath.row]
    print(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row])


    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        radioControllerChoice.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
    case 2:
        radioControllerDip.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
    default:
        print("no case found")
    }
    switch Int(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row]) {
    case 1:
        cell.radioBtn.isHidden = true
        cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = false
        break
    case 2:
        cell.radioBtn.isHidden = false

        cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = true
        break
    default:
        print("Invalid choose")

    }
    cell.radioBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.radioBtnaction), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.checkBoxBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkBoxBtnaction), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: SSRadioButtonsController() in that example three separate button is there, we can change it select and deselect. but here one single button display depends upon array. how we can change it.

Comment: i have also written the code for you , added two lines there 
var radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController()
radioButtonController.addButton(cell.radioBtn)

Comment: I tried this once more .. it is working perfectly .. if you are still facing this issue you can show me your code ..so that i can help

Comment: it working fine, but i want to make select and deselect option with sections separate. first sections choice it have 5 radio button[show in image] select any one option there. second Dip one radio button is there if i select that means choice radio button should not deselect. each sections want to separate select and deselect. help me

Comment: Ohk then make different radiocontroller instances for each sections and in cellForRow function add the radio buttons to their respective radiocontroller..

Comment: update my code what are the changes i done see on the question. check the func didSelectButton(selectedButton: UIButton?). i want all radio button select and deselect individually. if i select one radio button means it will selected. again i select other radio button means the first deselect, but i need one radio button select and deselect option in ios.

Comment: am not getting what else you want to do .. if you want to know which radio button is selected in section .. you can add different targets to each section radio button ...like didSelectChoice()... didSelectDip() .. and then get the selected radio using tag property

Comment: ok that fine i am saying, selected one radio button is selected, again i am click same radio button is not deselected. this my problem.

Comment: ohk use this line **radioControllerDip.shouldLetDeSelect = false** to diable the deselect option

Comment: now if i click the cheese radio button, Drink section radio button selected automatically, how to fix this problem.

Comment: now that's  another issue related to #reUsableCell.. i think you should ask it separetely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152126/discussion-between-preeti-rani-and-saravanar).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach:

1) Create a model for the button

2) take a enum defining cases of radio, check box

3) Create a normal button in your cell UI

4) Based on the enum status modify the button to be a radio button or checkbox, from your UI I guess changing the image on top of the button should do the trick

This way both buttons will have the same action handler, based on the models enum value you can then decide what actions are to be taken